# Monitoring Tool on Powershell that queries access

Tags: powershell, ms-access-2007

In theory I feel this should kinda be simple. Basically I need a query in access to be run every hour or so through powershell, and then if a certain condition in the query is met I need an email sent.

The email, and the query is simple enough, but I don't know how I can get powershell to query access, and I'm unsure if I can get it the query to run every hour. But if I can just get powershell to run a query on access I'll be happy enough.

Comment: ScheduledJob would do for the hourly part

Comment: You can utilize any OLE or ODBC connection that will talk with Access to connect and make the query. This might be of some help. [Powershell to read from database using ODBC;DNS instead of connectionstring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309969/powershell-to-read-from-database-using-odbcdns-instead-of-connectionstring)

Answer (score 2):

> if I can just get powershell to run a query on access I'll be happy enough

The "ACE.psm1" module referenced in the other answer looks useful, but if you prefer to "roll your own" code for database access you could use something like this:

```ps1
$connStr = @"
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb
"@
$con = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $connStr
$con.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand "SELECT * FROM Clients", $con
$rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
while ($rdr.Read())
{
    Write ("{0}, {1}" -f $rdr["LastName"], $rdr["FirstName"])
}
$rdr.Close()
$con.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

running some scriptblock hourly:

```
$command =  {

    $trigger = New-JobTrigger -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 60) -RepeatIndefinitely `
    -At (get-date) -Once

    $job = Register-ScheduledJob -Name 'Test' -Trigger $trigger -ScriptBlock {
        (Get-Date).DateTime | Out-File D:\test.txt -Append
    } 
}
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noprofile -command $Command" -Verb runas
```

have a look the ACE module here:

[Use ACE Drivers and PowerShell to Talk to Access and Excel](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/04/use-ace-drivers-and-powershell-to-talk-to-access-and-excel.aspx)